# Why is my function not doing anything with this one specific .o file?

Tags: c, makefile, output

When I run my makefile, the `printHeader.o` file is not created. My makefile is depicted below:

```
all: mkprog

mkprog: main.o printlist.o insertNode.o printLine.o readfile.o totalCatGrade.o option1.o
    gcc main.o printlist.o insertNode.o printLine.o printHeader.o readfile.o totalCatGrade.o option1.o -o mkprog

main.o:main.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c main.c -o main.o

printlist.o:printlist.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c printlist.c -o printlist.o

insertNode.o:insertNode.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c insertNode.c -o insertNode.o

printLine.o:printLine.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c printLine.c -o printLine.o

printHeader.o:printHeader.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c printHeader.c -o printHeader.o

readfile.o:readfile.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c readfile.c -o readfile.o

totalCatGrade.o:totalCatGrade.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c totalCatGrade.c -o totalCatGrade.o

option1.o:option1.c lab4.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c option1.c -o option1.o


clean:
    rm -rf *.o mkprog
```

I tried moving it around in the lines of the function. I tried deleting the other .o files and running makefile again.

Comment: Welcome. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and learn how to properly format your posts.

Comment: which specific .o file?

Comment: Why do you think it should be created? Where did you tell the computer to create it?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to put the printheader.o in the first line of mkprog

Comment: I was literally typing that out now... but I'm glad you found it yourself.

Comment: There are more intelligent and less error prone ways to write makefiles. This tutorial explains it pretty well: https://makefiletutorial.com/